# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 32-bit on two separate HDDs

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I am having issues installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 32-bit on two separate drives, one is a HDD and the other is a SSD.  Currently Windows 7 32-bit is installed on the SSD (Disk 1), however, it installed some System Reserve 100 MB on the HDD (Disk 0).  Since it's a Windows 7 32-bit version it is not installed as UEFI.  How would I go about installing Ubuntu 14.04 on the HDD (Disk 0).

When I choose something else to create my own partitions I am confused on what to do.

Under /dev/sda 
 free space                          120034 MB (which I thought windows was installed)

Under /dev/sdb 
 /dev/sdb1 ntfs                      104 MB 25 MB (which I believe is the System Reserve)
 free space                          2000293 MB (which is the HDD)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to createthese partitions in the free space:

1. If you want to use swap memory (HDD space the OS can use to temporarily store RAM content, e.g. if the RAM runs short or when hibernating), create a SWAP partition with the size of your RAM.

Do you want to keep a separate `/home` partition? If yes, you should spend some thought on how to split the remaining space. As your HDD is 2TiB, I'd suggest 1:3, i.e. ~1500GiB for the home partition and the rest for the system parition.

2. Create the system partition: EXT4, Mount point: `/`. If you don't wan a separate home, use the remaining space, else the space you decided to use.
3. Create another EXT4 partition, mount point `/home`.
4. Select `/dev/sda` (SSD, because it's faster) for the bootloader installation (at the bottom) and start the installation.

After the installation finished, go into your BIOS setup and verify that the SSD is set as the primary boot device (at least higher than the HDD) and then boot Ubuntu.

It may happen that the OS selection menu doesn't show up. In this case, open the file `/etc/default/grub` in Ubuntu (as root): `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and change the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `10`. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then run `sudo update-grub`.